# AWS EC2 Ubuntu crashing

Tags: networking, 22.04, crash, aws

I am using AWS EC2 with `ubuntu 22`. After running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` I have restarted the machine using `sudo reboot`.

Then my server started crashing in every 2-3 hours. The only solution is to restart from `console.aws.amazon.com` website.

The logs say

```
[   30.811643] cloud-init[293]: Cloud-init v. 23.4.4-0ubuntu0~22.04.1
running 'init-local' at Fri, 08 Mar 2024 03:15:31 +0000. Up 30.76
seconds. 
[   31.932494]
================================================================================ [   31.940631] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in
/build/linux-aws-6.5-4tw9h1/linux-aws-6.5-6.5.0/drivers/net/xen-netfront.c:1323:3
[   31.949710] index 1 is out of range for type
'xen_netif_rx_sring_entry [1]' 
[   31.965154]
================================================================================ [   32.126461]
================================================================================ [   32.134793] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in
/build/linux-aws-6.5-4tw9h1/linux-aws-6.5-6.5.0/drivers/net/xen-netfront.c:502:7
[   32.145800] index 1 is out of range for type
'xen_netif_tx_sring_entry [1]' 
[   32.152066]
================================================================================ 
[   32.159001]
================================================================================ [   32.167055] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in
/build/linux-aws-6.5-4tw9h1/linux-aws-6.5-6.5.0/drivers/net/xen-netfront.c:430:4
[   32.176208] index 1 is out of range for type
'xen_netif_tx_sring_entry [1]' 
[   32.184067]
================================================================================ [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mInitial cloud-init job
(pre-networking)[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target
[0;1;39mPreparation for Network[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mNetwork Configuration[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mNetwork Configuration[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mWait for Network to be Configured[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mNetwork Name Resolution[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mNetwork Name Resolution[0m. [[0;32m  OK 
[0m] Reached target [0;1;39mNetwork[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached
target [0;1;39mHost and Network Name Lookups[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m]
Finished [0;1;39mWait for Network to be Configured[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mInitial cloud-ini… (metadata service crawler)[0m... [   36.329724] cloud-init[323]: Cloud-init v.
23.4.4-0ubuntu0~22.04.1 running 'init' at Fri, 08 Mar 2024 03:15:37 +0000. Up 36.30 seconds. [   36.348170] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
 [   36.368656]
cloud-init[323]: ci-info:
+--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+ [   36.384720] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: | Device |  Up  |          
Address           |      Mask     | Scope  |     Hw-Address    | [  
36.406316] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+ [   36.428641] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: |  eth0  | True |        
172.31.6.227        | 255.255.240.0 | global | 0a:4c:be:e0:20:fe | [   36.444572] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: |  eth0  | True | fe80::84c:beff:fee0:20fe/64 |       .       |  link  |
0a:4c:be:e0:20:fe | [   36.464092] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: |   lo  
| True |          127.0.0.1          |   255.0.0.0   |  host  |       
.         | [   36.481933] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: |   lo   | True |
::1/128           |       .       |  host  |         .         | [  
36.490025] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+ [   36.500428] cloud-init[323]: ci-info:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route IPv4 info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ [   36.512666] cloud-init[323]:
ci-info:
+-------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+ [   36.528722] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: | Route | Destination | 
Gateway   |     Genmask     | Interface | Flags | [   36.544510]
cloud-init[323]: ci-info:
+-------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+ [   36.558908] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: |   0   |   0.0.0.0   |
172.31.0.1 |     0.0.0.0     |    eth0   |   UG  | [   36.567355] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: |   1   |  172.31.0.0 |  0.0.0.0   | 
255.255.240.0  |    eth0   |   U   | [   36.574037] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: |   2   |  172.31.0.1 |  0.0.0.0   | 255.255.255.255 |   
eth0   |   UH  | [   36.581876] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: |   3   | 
172.31.0.2 |  0.0.0.0   | 255.255.255.255 |    eth0   |   UH  | [   36.590398] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+ [   36.598906] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++Route IPv6
info+++++++++++++++++++ [   36.607608] cloud-init[323]: ci-info:
+-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+ [   36.617366] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: | Route | Destination | Gateway | Interface
| Flags | [   36.625431] cloud-init[323]: ci-info:
+-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+ [   36.634057] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: |   1   |  fe80::/64  |    ::   |    eth0  
|   U   | [   36.645677] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: |   3   |    local 
|    ::   |    eth0   |   U   | [   36.655523] cloud-init[323]:
ci-info: |   4   |  multicast  |    ::   |    eth0   |   U   | [  
36.664180] cloud-init[323]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+ [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mInitial cloud-ini…ob (metadata service
crawler)[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mCloud-config
availability[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mNetwork
is Online[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSystem
Initialization[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mACPI Events
Check[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily Cleanup of
Temporary Directories[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mUbuntu
Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m]
Started [0;1;39mDownload data for …ailed at package install time[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mPath Units[0m. [[0;32m 
OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mACPID Listen Socket[0m. [[0;32m  OK 
[0m] Listening on [0;1;39mcloud-init hotplug hook socket[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mD-Bus System Message Bus
Socket[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mOpen-iSCSI
iscsid Socket[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mSocket
unix for snap application lxd.daemon[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m]
Listening on [0;1;39mSocket unix f…p application lxd.user-daemon[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mSocket activation for snappy daemon[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mUUID daemon activation
socket[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mPreparation
for Remote File Systems[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target
[0;1;39mRemote File Systems[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished
[0;1;39mAvailability of block devices[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m]
Listening on [0;1;39mSocket activation for snappy daemon[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSocket Units[0m. [[0;32m
OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mBasic System[0m. [[0;32m  OK 
[0m] Started [0;1;39mACPI event daemon[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mThe Apache HTTP Server[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mLSB: automatic crash report generation[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mchrony, an NTP client/server[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mRegular background program
processing daemon[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mD-Bus
System Message Bus[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mSave
initial kernel messages after boot[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mRemove Stale Onli…t4 Metadata Check Snapshots[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mEC2 Instance Connect Host Key Harvesting[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mRecord successful boot for GRUB[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mirqbalance daemon[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mMySQL Community Server[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mDispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mSystem Logging Service[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mService for snap
a…on-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mService for snap application lxd.activate[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mUserspace
listener for prompt events[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target
[0;1;39mPreparation for Logins[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mSnap Daemon[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mUser Login Management[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mPermit User Sessions[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mSystem Logging Service[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mHostname Service[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mPermit User Sessions[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mHold until boot process finishes up[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mTerminate Plymouth Boot Screen[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mHold until boot process finishes
up[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mTerminate Plymouth Boot
Screen[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mSerial Getty on
ttyS0[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mSet console scheme[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mRecord successful boot for GRUB[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mGRUB failed boot detection[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mLSB: automatic crash report generation[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mSet console scheme[0m. [[0;32m
OK  [0m] Created slice [0;1;39mSlice /system/getty[0m. [[0;32m  OK
[0m] Started [0;1;39mGetty on tty1[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached
target [0;1;39mLogin Prompts[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started
[0;1;39mHostname Service[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mAuthorization Manager[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mGRUB failed boot detection[0m. [[0;32m  OK 
[0m] Started [0;1;39mUser Login Management[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m]
Started [0;1;39mUnattended Upgrades Shutdown[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m]
Started [0;1;39mchrony, an NTP client/server[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m]
Reached target [0;1;39mSystem Time Synchronized[0m. [[0;32m  OK 
[0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily apt download activities[0m. [[0;32m  OK
[0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily apt upgrade and clean activities[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mRun certbot twice daily[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily dpkg database backup
timer[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mPeriodic ext4 Onli…ata
Check for All Filesystems[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started
[0;1;39mDiscard unused blocks once a week[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m]
Started [0;1;39mDaily rotation of log files[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m]
Started [0;1;39mDaily man-db regeneration[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m]
Started [0;1;39mMessage of the Day[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started
[0;1;39mClean PHP session files every 30 mins[0m. [[0;32m  OK 
[0m] Started [0;1;39mCheck to see wheth…w version of Ubuntu
available[0m. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mTimer
Units[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mClean php session files[0m... [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mAuthorization Manager[0m. [   42.292707]
================================================================================ [   42.298815] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in
/build/linux-aws-6.5-4tw9h1/linux-aws-6.5-6.5.0/drivers/net/xen-netfront.c:824:4
[   42.309057] index 136 is out of range for type
'xen_netif_tx_sring_entry [1]' [   42.318190]
================================================================================ [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mEC2 Instance Connect Host Key
Harvesting[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mOpenBSD Secure Shell server[0m...



Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS ip-172-31-6-227 ttyS0

ip-172-31-6-227 login: [   57.597024] cloud-init[724]: Cloud-init v.
23.4.4-0ubuntu0~22.04.1 running 'modules:config' at Fri, 08 Mar 2024 03:15:58 +0000. Up 57.54 seconds. [   74.431229] cloud-init[826]:
Cloud-init v. 23.4.4-0ubuntu0~22.04.1 running 'modules:final' at Fri,
08 Mar 2024 03:16:15 +0000. Up 74.37 seconds. [   74.580364]
cloud-init[826]: Cloud-init v. 23.4.4-0ubuntu0~22.04.1 finished at
Fri, 08 Mar 2024 03:16:15 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2Local.  Up
74.57 seconds
```

**EDIT : 9 March**

After adding Cloudwatch I got below notification

> Ensure the instance role has appropriate SSM permissions, the security
> group allows egress, and the instance is able to communicate with SSM
> through either a VPC Endpoint or through the instance's VPC Internet
> Gateway

I have added policy as per recommendation but after a few hours I got another notification which say

> Log group APPLICATION-ApplicationInsights-Will-Application-Insight has
> not set log path for component
> arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:50882112742:instance/i-0f46de45f500d9d6.

I still don't know what causing this?

Comment: You do NOT upgrade cloud instances: any crash during boot is fatal and upgrades can go wrong. You make a new disk in the AWS console with the new OS version and mount your userdata into that new disk.  Please restore the backup of your disk from the AWS console.  Othewise you will likely need to make a new disk. If you need to get content out of this one: make a new disk mount this old one into the new one and copy your files over.

Comment: @Rinzwind is there any solution as I do not have snapshot

Comment: No idea :( I do not see any errors in the text you gave (i made it a blockquote so it is scrollable ;) )  I checked what you see here against one of our servers and this seems correct.  One way to restore your system (but a lot of work :P )  create a new instance. detach this instance and attach this one as a 2nd disk to the new instance. That way you get it mounted and you can extract your data and put it into the new one.

Comment: what about `UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds` is it normal?

I found that it is a know bug https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net&q=subject:%22%5C%5BKernel%5C-packages%5C%5D+%5C%5BBug+1983357%5C%5D+Re%5C%3A+test_021_aslr_dapper_libs+from%09ubuntu_qrt_kernel_security+failed+on+K%5C-5.19+%5C%2F+J%5C-OEM%5C-6.1+%5C%2F%09J%5C-6.2+AMD64%22&o=newest&f=1

Comment: no that one is harmless; not responsible for a crash.

Comment: How to check what causing the crash?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this was a bug in Linux's driver for Xen. It got fixed a few months ago, but that bugfix hasn't made its way to Ubuntu yet. [There's a bug report on Launchpad tracking this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-aws/+bug/2058480).

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy, LTS), and I'm seeing very similar UBSAN errors in my logs — though fortunately, this hasn't been causing my server to crash. And as far as I can tell from looking at the code, the latest Ubuntu (23.10/mantic) is also affected as well.